# Attr() is not showing

Tags: jquery

I don't understand why attr() isn't working (see code below). I can see correct  tag with the attribute in sources, tag is creating but it's not visible on the website.

```
app.html('<h1>' + product.name + '</h1><img src="' + product.img + '" width="300"></img><a></a>');
$('a').attr("href", product.link);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No content is in the `<a>` tag. That's why.

```html
<a>1st tag</a>
<a></a><!--Second tag-->
```

Comment: Oh yes. I have to go to sleep I guess :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**1st**: by using *not visible on the website.* this is because the `<a></a>` doesn't have any content

**2nd** : about the `</img>` you can take a look at [Why is the <img> tag not closed in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890716/why-is-the-img-tag-not-closed-in-html)