# Href area too, big, tried inline-block

Tags: html, css, href

so my problem is, that I can't make href area image-sized. I still get white border up, left, right of my image, I tried display: inline-block, without any luck. This is my CSS (I know it looks pretty awful):

```css
div.gallery {
  margin: 1%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 25px #000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 25px #000;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 25px #000;
  float: left;
  min-width: 180px;
  width: 23%;
}

div.gallery a {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block !important;
}

div.gallery img {
  display: block;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <a href="myphoto.jpg">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x150&text=myphoto.jpg" alt="" />
  </a>
  <div class="desc">XXX</div>
</div>


<div class="gallery">
  <a target="_blank" href="myphoto.jpg">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x150&text=myphoto.jpg" alt="" />
  </a>
  <div class="desc">XXX</div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Thanks for answer, but I think I could be a little unclear:

I made a gallery, that displays 4 imgs in a row, no matter if the screen resolution is hd, or 1024x768. It's responsive. in div.gallery img I set width to be 100% (which I forgot to add here). My problem is, that I have something like this when setting  on the images: [white border caused by a href](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sosuy.jpg).

Comment: Consider making a code snippet or a jsfiddle to better illustrate your problem

Comment: When I'm making a jsfiddle, there's no white border around image, also when I copy all the code to make a simple webpage (not in wordpress), everything works fine. I'm very confused right now...

Comment: Your code on its own here  seems buggy (image not resized) .  For the borders, you might need to reset them on those specific images probably inherited from other rules or heavier selector. it can also be shadows and not borders. you'll need to dig in your code about each rules applied to links or image. Finally, i would eventually suggest to use figure and figcaption and set links as block elements. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BdXLvL

Answer (score 0):

The `a inline-block` element will not expand if its contents have no dimension. Once I set a dimension to the `img` than it works.

```css
img {
  width:180px;
  height:100px;
}

div.gallery {
margin: 1%; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 25px #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 25px #000; 

 box-shadow: 10px 10px 25px #000; 
 float: left;
 min-width: 180px;
 width: 23%;
 }

 div.gallery a {
 background-color: red;
 display: inline-block;
 }


 div.gallery img {
 display:inline-block;
 }

 div.desc {

 padding: 15px;
 text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="gallery">
 <a href="myphoto.jpg">
 <img src="myphoto.jpg" alt="" />
 </a>
 <div class="desc">XXX</div>
 </div>


 <div class="gallery">
 <a target="_blank" href="myphoto.jpg">
 <img src="myphoto.jpg" alt="" />
 </a>
 <div class="desc">XXX</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a really simple fix for this.

Simply wrap your a around the div too, then set, on your images: `height="48px" width="100%" position: absolute;`

Finally, set the width of your anchors to 100%;

Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/v45k8ojk/2/

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code for solve your problem.

```css
div.gallery {
margin: 1%; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px #000; 
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px #000; 
 float: left;
 min-width: 160px;
 width: 25%;
 }

 div.gallery a{
 width: 100%;
 background-color: yellow;
 display: inline-block !important;
 }

 div.gallery img {
 display:block;
 position: absolute;
 }

 div.desc {
 padding: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="gallery">
 <a href="myphoto.jpg">
 <img src="myphoto.jpg" alt="" height="100px" width="100%" />
 <div class="desc">AAA</div>
 </a>
 </div>

 <div class="gallery">
 <a target="_blank" href="myphoto.jpg">
 <img src="myphoto.jpg" alt="" height="100px" width="100%" />
 <div class="desc">BBB</div>
 </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try changing

```
<img src="myphoto.jpg" alt="" />
```

to

```
<img src="myphoto.jpg" alt="image1">
```

Image tag does not require end of the tag.

Comment: It does not require it, but both are accepted. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890716/why-is-the-img-tag-not-closed-in-html for more information. Generally, what you have suggested would be more widely used, however.