# img src gives Template parse errors in angular2

Tags: html, angular

My code is as shown below:

test.html

```
<div class="q-img-container">
    <img id="q-order-img" src="../img/ic_truck.png" alt=""></img>
</div>
```

But it gives me following error:

```
"Unhandled Promise rejection:"
"Template parse errors:
Void elements do not have end tags "img" ("iv class="q-img-container">
                <img id="q-order-img" src="../img/ic_truck.png" alt="">[ERROR ->]</img>
            </div>
```

My directory structure is as follows:

```
---app
------img
----------ic_truck.png
------template
----------test.html
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: remove the end tag </img>

Comment: Yes, it worked. The above line in question worked fine in angular 1 , why it is rejected in angular2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`img` tag is a `void element`. Such elements *cannot* have any content and are forbidden to be closed ([W3C recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements)).

As the error message says, remove the end tag `</img>`.

Just use following

```
<img id="q-order-img" src="../img/ic_truck.png" alt="">
```

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890716/why-is-the-img-tag-not-closed-in-html).