# How to style the tags present in document.write()?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to style the img tag present inside document.write(). How to do it?

I tried using img{height:100px; width:100px;} inside style tag in head but I don't think that's how it works.

```
     <form name="myform" style="margin-left: 45%">
     <input type="radio" name="ward" value="Thane">Thane</input><br>
     <input type="radio" name="ward" value="Vashi">Vashi</input><br>
     <input type="radio" name="ward" value="Andheri">Andheri</input><br>
     <input type="radio" name="ward" value="Bandra">Bandra</input><br>
     <input type="radio" name="ward" value="Dadar">Dadar</input><br>
     <button onclick="display()" id="submit">Submit</button>
     </form>

      Above code is inside body of html and below code is inside script

      if(document.myform.ward.value=="Thane")
      {
        document.write("Thank You!<br>You have selected Thane");
         document.write("<img src='voted.gif'></img>");
       }
```

I want the image and thank you message for Thane to get displayed only when user selects Thane. But I am not able to style the image. how to do it? I cant use innerHTML as it gets displayed on the same page where I'm selecting options and I don't want that. I'm a beginner so don't know how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: `document.write("<img class='image' src='voted.gif'></img>");` and then inside style tag, do `.image{height:100px; width:100px;} `

Comment: @weegee That's not working but thanks

Comment: @weegee — `document.write` destroys the existing document, so the style won't exist afterwards.

Comment: @Quentin this works https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G6FF1DPEFL2U

Comment: @weegee — That only works because the original document hasn't been closed when your document.write statement runs. The OP is reading form data, so they must be doing it after the document has closed and the user has started interacting with it.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is usually not recommended, you can use inline styling like so:

```
document.write("<img src='voted.gif' style='height:100px; width:100px;'>");
```

You do not have to close the img tag as it is a [void](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890716/why-is-the-img-tag-not-closed-in-html/23890817) element.

Comment: @N97 Try my answer is better for this things. This method is truly not recommended how say user of this answer ers36.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried get an element via for example 
`document.getElementsByTagName("some_tag_name")`

With `getElementsByTagName` you can get an element, with an element you can use a **style** object and get or set properties of an element.

`document.getElementsByTagName("some_tag_name").style.some_style_propertie = "some_value_of_propertie";`

An example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="myDiv">This is a div.</div>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Set solid border</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.borderStyle = "solid";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Link of style object Javascript:** https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp

Comment: The question is about styling an element that has been `document.write`n, not one that exists in the current document. (Note that `document.write` creates a new document.)

Comment: You can create a new element via https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp i **don't recommend** ``document.write`` the problem is for example if you want insert an element down of some elements named parents, how can you do it with document.write i don't will be answer no recommended methods for this things like the op request. OK?

Comment: I don't recommend document.write either … but the question is specifically about using it … and your answer just gives a solution that assumes document.write *isn't* used rather then demonstrating how to rewrite the OP's original code to remove document.write while still achieving the goal they want.

Comment: OK, can i add an ``document.write`` example and say its not recommended and put my ``.style`` example and how create an element via ``createElement`` function ?