# Trim space between tags

Tags: regex

I want to trim any space between tags.

E.g. `<div> umesh kumar </div>` should become `<div>umesh kumar</div>`

This should work for any tags.

Tried using may patterns but none of them worked.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"/>[ \t]+</");
string newContent = regex.Replace(fileContent, "><");
```

Comment: eh any space between tags means also the space between umesh_kumar? is the space only at start and end of names?

Comment: HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable. [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)

Comment: it should take off the space between the tags but not between contents " <div> umesh kumar </div> should be converted to <div>umesh kumar</div>, It should work for all tags

Comment: Can I give you a solution that doesn't include regex? This can easily be done using C#.

Comment: Hi  @DxTx My Situation is like this I am reading content from text file which contains below contents <iD> test data </Id> <Sub_Tab> test data </sub_tab> <form> form data </form>. My requrement is whatever i have inside ID,Sub_tab tags i want to take off the trailing and leading spaces from the content inside those tags , but the content inside the form tag should be untouched.     Being said that my output should come as iD>test data</Id> <Sub_Tab>test data</sub_tab> <form> form data </form>.

Answer (score 1):

Search for this: `>\s*([^<>]*?)\s*<`

- `\s` means any white space
- `([^<>\s]*?)` is anything that is not a tag in a group

  - `[^<>]` matches anything that is not `<` or `>`
  - `*?` is to match multiple characters in non-greedy manner so it doesn't collect white space at the end that is collected by ending `\s*`

Replace with this: `>\1<`

- `\1` is the first (and only) group.

Comment: Try it with: `<div> blah <span> blah </span> </div>`

Comment: Tried with this Regex regex = new Regex(@" >\s*(.*)\s*<");
string newContent = regex.Replace(fileContent, "><");  Didn't worked

Comment: Yes, because '.*' is too greedy and will include tags in between. This answer was bad. I just updated it. @UmeshKumar

Comment: Doesn't work with: `<div> 3 > 2 </div>`. Don't parse HTML with regex.

Comment: @Toto `<div> 3 > 2 </div>` is not valid html. If you want `>` symbol in the value, you should use `&gt;` EDIT: but I agree with you, there are far more reliable parsers available for HTML and regex is a dirty hack.

Comment: Also my tag comes like this too <div> Umesh Kumar </div> also with underscore <sub_id> data <sub_id>

Comment: @UmeshKumar this should not affect the above regex in any way. It's only matching "the body" of tags.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please provide me a sample  c# code for this also is there a way to exclude a particular tag when we do regex replace. Like we have div tag and image tag . I want to apply only this replace for every thing else image tag

Comment: @UmeshKumar I don't understand. Image tags don't have a closing tag. There is no text in between. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890716/why-is-the-img-tag-not-closed-in-html/23890817

Comment: Hi  @PredragMandic Mandic My Situation is like this I am reading content from text file which contains below contents <iD> test data </Id> <Sub_Tab> test data </sub_tab> <form> form data </form>. My requrement is whatever i have inside ID,Sub_tab tags i want to take off the trailing and leading spaces from the content inside those tags , but the content inside the form tag should be untouched.     Being said that my output should come as iD>test data</Id> <Sub_Tab>test data</sub_tab> <form> form data </form>.

Comment: @UmeshKumar so is it images or form? what about tags that are within form tag? It seems to me like you are diverging from your initial question too much. It might be a good idea to start a new post and mark this one as answered if it answered your original question.