# lxml parser removing <img> closing tag when parsing html

Tags: python-2.7, lxml

I have the below HTML content:

```
<html>

<body>
    <div>
        <p><img class="img.jpg" /></p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and i am trying to parse the HTML using `lxml` parser as below:

```
import lxml.html as LH
root = LH.fromstring(html)
for el in root.iter('img'):
    el.attrib['src'] = el.attrib['class']
content = '<html><body>' + LH.tostring(root) + '</body></html>'
```

I am getting the content after parsing as below:

```
<html>

<body>
    <div>
        <p><img class="img.jpg" src="img.jpg"></p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, the `<img>`'s closing tag `</>` has been removed after parsing. Is there anyway I can retain all the HTML closing tags after HTML parsing?

Comment: Is there any way i can achieve using html parser of lxml or I have to use xml parser of lxml?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the <img> tag not closed in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890716/why-is-the-img-tag-not-closed-in-html)

Comment: I think it is not needed in HTML - please see the linked question. Will it work if you parse as XML?